# I am unable to ask a question on aviation stack exchange?

Tags: support

I am unable  to ask a question on aviation stack exchange

Comment: Details?  We are not tech support, you may need to do a search for that...

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"? Which step doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 12):

From looking at the logs, it looks like you've hit several issues:

- A question hit the [quality check](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

  The quality filter is a bit on the dumb side, so it doesn't actually know whether your question is interesting or useful. Instead it looks at various secondary indicators. Looking at the body of the question you submitted, I think you can get around it with some more details.
- You failed the [CAPTCHA](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/captcha).

  This happens to me all the time and it's really annoying. We switched to the [new reCAPTCHA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244638/1438), which really helps, if you get it. Unfortunately, you don't always get it.
- The [new user question throttle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/1438) was tripped.

  I'm not sure what triggered it this time, but it can be triggered by [someone else on your IP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66859/1438). I suspect it can also be triggered by the above failures.

Obviously, your actual contributions have been [well received](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/16123/simba?tab=reputation), so this is just our system being stupid. If you put more details in your question and try again, I bet you'll be able to ask it without problems.